# Need regex expression with multiple conditions

Tags: regex

I need regex with following conditions

- It should accept maximum of 5 digits then upto 3 decimal places
- it can be negative
- it can be zero
- it can be only numbers (max. upto 5 digit place)
- it can be null

I have tried following but its not, its not fulfilling all conditions

```
@"^([\-\+]?)\d{0,5}(.[0-9]{1,3})?)$"
```

E.g. maximum value can hold is from -99999.999 to 99999.999

Comment: For one thing, you need to escape the `.` like `\.`. When it's a bare dot, it means "any character" which will definitely cause you some pain here. If you can, I recommend doing the blank/null check outside the regex. Like: `valueIsOk = value.blank? || value.match?(regex)`. If not, just slap another `?` outside the last close parenthesis.

Comment: Your fourth rule contradicts your first rule. Your pattern implements a start-of-line and end-of-line rule that aren't stated in your rules. No regular expression can handle `null`: do you mean 'empty'? If I was given this as a specification I would reject it as  ambiguous.

Comment: @EJP If you feel this way then why did you answer?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Because it's important for posters to know when their stated requirements are mutually contradictory, and ditto for future readers of the question. I answered it as best I could, but issues certainly remain. Same can be said of your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
^[-+]?\d{0,5}(\.[0-9]{1,3})?$
```

I only made two changes here.  First, you *don't* need to escape any characters inside a character class normally, except for opening and closing brackets, or possibly backslash itself.  Hence, we can use `[-+]` to capture an initial plus or minus.  Second, you need to escape the dot in your regex, to tell the engine that you want to match a literal dot.

However, I would probably phrase this regex as follows:

```
^[-+]?\d{1,5}(\.[0-9]{1,3})?$
```

This will match one to five digits, followed by an optional decimal point, followed by one to three digits.

Note that we want to capture things like:

```
0.123
```

But not

```
.123
```

i.e. we don't want to capture a leading decimal point should it not be prefixed by at least one number.

**Demo here:**

## Regex101

Comment: sorry for confusion... upto i mean that 5 digits upto 99999 or upto three decimal places i mean .999 that max it can hold

Comment: ^[-+]?\d{0,5}(\.[0-9]{1,3})?$ , is perfect as it allows both .123 and 0.123 , user usually input with 0 before decimal

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're doing this in C# given the notation. Here's a little code you can use to test your expression, with two corrections:

1. You have to escape the dot, otherwise it means "any character". So, `\.` instead of `.`
2. There was an extraneous close parenthesis that prevented the expression from compiling

C#:

```
var expr = @"^([\-\+]?)\d{0,5}(\.[0-9]{1,3})?$";
var re = new Regex(expr);
string[] samples = {
    "",
    "0",
    "1.1",
    "1.12",
    "1.123",
    "12.3",
    "12.34",
    "12.345",
    "123.4",
    "12345.123",
    ".1",
    ".1234"
};
foreach(var s in samples) {
    Console.WriteLine("Testing [{0}]: {1}", s, re.IsMatch(s) ? "PASS" : "FAIL");
}
```

Results:

```
Testing []: PASS
Testing [0]: PASS
Testing [1.1]: PASS
Testing [1.12]: PASS
Testing [1.123]: PASS
Testing [12.3]: PASS
Testing [12.34]: PASS
Testing [12.345]: PASS
Testing [123.4]: PASS
Testing [12345.123]: PASS
Testing [.1]: PASS
Testing [.1234]: FAIL
```

Comment: sorry for confusion... upto i mean that 5 digits upto 99999 or upto three decimal places i mean .999 that max it can hold

Answer (score 0):

> It should accept maximum of 5 digits

```
[0-9]{1,5}
```

> then upto 3 decimal places

```
 [0-9]{1,5}(\.[0-9]{1,3})?
```

> it can be negative

```
 [-]?[0-9]{1,5}(\.[0-9]{1,3})?
```

> it can be zero

Already covered.

> it can be only numbers (max. upto 5 digit place)

Already covered. 'Up to 5 digit place' contradicts your first rule, which allows 5.3.

> it can be null

Not covered. I ***strongly*** suggest you remove this requirement. Even if you mean 'empty', as I sincerely hope you do, you should detect that case separately and beforehand, as you will certainly have to handle it differently.

Your regular expression contains `^` and `$`. I don't know why. There is nothing about start of line or end of line in the rules you specified. It also allows a leading `+`, which again isn't specified in your rules.